# Shared folder write-self, read all permission

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, ntfs

We wanted a shared folder where employees can add and modify their own files, but only had “Read” permission to the files other employees have created.

How can we set permissions for this folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this solution:
 - Set "Change" share permissions on the folder.
 - Then set up NTFS permissions (Folder Properties -> Security -> Advanced):
 -   Disable inheritance -> Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object
 -   For appropriate user group ("Users" in my case) set "Read & execute" permissions that applies to "This folder, subfolders and files"
 -   For the same group set "Modify" permission that applies to "This folder and subfolders"[image]